# OpenCV - Playback CPU usage

Tags: c++, opencv, h.264

I'm working on project that requires to play two recorded videos in both directions (forward or backward).

Both videos recorded in parallel using H.264 encoding.

I have written a very simple code (see below) in C++ using OpenCV 3.2.0:

To control playback direction I have defined two flags ("**play_left_backward**", "**play_right_backward**)

If I set both flags to "false" the code runs using less than one percent of CPU.

If I set only one of the flags to "true" the code runs using around 2% of CPU.

But if I set both flags to "true" the code runs using **28%** of CPU.

I cannot understand the reason for such weird behavior.

Is anyone have any explanation ?

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

int main() {

   bool play_left_backward = true;
   bool play_right_backward = true;

   cv::Mat frame_left;
   cv::Mat frame_right;

   cv::VideoCapture cap_left("D:\\record_left.avi");
   cv::VideoCapture cap_right("D:\\record_right.avi");

   // amount of frames
   int N = (int)cap_left.get(7);

   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

       if (play_left_backward == true) {
          cap_left.set(1, N - i - 1);
       }

       if (play_right_backward == true) {
          cap_right.set(1, N - i - 1);
       }

       cap_left >> frame_left;
       cap_right >> frame_right;

       cv::imshow("Frame left", frame_left);
       cv::imshow("Frame right", frame_right);

       char c = (char)cv::waitKey(30);
       if (c == 27) {
          break;
       }

   }

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How are you getting this benchmark? Using the value the OS reports to benchmark your app is iffy at best.

Comment: Is there a chance that GPU decoding is used if playing forward, but CPU decoding is used when playing backward? (get some tool that shows your GPU usage and check)